Using a parameter as a macro in system verilog code
Assume that I have below module definition with a parameter N:
module my_mod #(parameter N=4) (
                                   input  logic [N-1:0] a,
                                   input  logic         b,
                                   output logic [N-1:0] c
                               )

assign c =  (b == 1'b1) ? a : 4'b0;

endmodule

Looking at the port declaration and parameter value, one can say that the signal c is 4 bits wide. However, is it possible to use the parameter N itself in some way such that in the assign statement above, the last operand (4'b0) can be represented somehow using this parameter N? For example:
assign c = (b == 1'b1) ? a : {N}'b0;

My take was using a `define macro and re-declaring N, but wanted to know if there is a way to tell the compiler on the fly to create a macro-type copy of the input parameter.

You can use parameters just like constants - for indexing, calculations, concatenation, etc.
In your example, the syntax you are looking for is the replication operation:
{(N){value}}

That would replicate the value N times to form a larger value. If you enter 1'b0 for the value, you would get an N-bit wider 0 constant.
However in this case it is somewhat unnecessary. Simply using 1'b0 would be sufficient on its own, as constants will be implicitly padded to the correct width:
assign c = (b == 1'b1) ? a : 1'b0;

It might be useful in cases where you want  all 1's (e.g. {(N){1'b1}}).

In SystemVerilog you can use unsized literals (e.g. '0, '1) to set all bits to the same value. The width of unsized literals is determined by the context. It should work out for itself that the ternary operator is N-bit because the other argument to the ternary operator is N-bit and so size the literal accordingly.

Actually I was trying to see if I could alias a parameter to a define macro and use it all throughout the design. Something like  define LENGTH = Nand then use this macroN` elsewhere in the design. Not sure if it is possible.

You can do this by assigning a default value of the parameter with the macro.  As a general rule, it is better to use parameters for synthesizable portion of your design and macros for the compile time variables.  This gives you the ability to have instances of the same module with different parameters by overriding the default value.
